# yet another internet explorer 9 ssl issue with facebook application

Tags: security, facebook-credits

I saw so many threads about this but nothing worked so far...
So I have my application, and if its accessed without https (such as http://apps.face... if accessed with https:// everything works) explorer goes crazy and a dialog opens at the bottom:
only secured content is displayed (what is this).
the error prevents the facebook credits dialog from opening, but still allows the friends invite dialog to open... odd...

the ie9 console shows many lines such as:

HTTPS security is compromised by http://profile.ak.fbcdn.net/hprofile-ak-snc4/211650_610002617_527396

then I found in an older thread that I should add the following line of JS before the fb.init phase:

```
FB._https = true;
```

and this:

```
FB._https = (window.location.protocol == "https:");
```

after using these the dialog stopped, but still I got these errors:

SCRIPT5: Access is denied.

canvas_proxy.php?version=3, line 89 character 3

I made sure to use :

both in the channel and head...

Still - the apprequest dialog opens, but not the facebook credit.

thanks for reading this, maybe someone got any idea?

Comment: Just saw it generates "permissions denied  canvas_proxy.php" error in explorer 8

Comment: are you fetching and displaying profile pictures of users in your application?

Comment: Yes, i made sure to call them from https, i hope that's enough...

Comment: Have you looked at it using the dev console from within Firefox?  What is actually causing the issue?

Comment: In my case the problem come from the top FB window loaded in http and the inner iframe app loaded in https creating some mixed content warning. Setting `FB._https` to `true` removed the warning, but did not fixed the payment popup. I'm trying to find another way.

Comment: Just another thing to check if this happens - make sure the script call in the channel file set to https...

Comment: Hi, did you found some solution for this problem? Are the missing contexts the cause for the error? Regards

Answer (score 0):

The full error message:

```
Webpage error details

User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 5.2; Trident/4.0; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.04506.648; .NET CLR 3.5.21022; .NET CLR 3.0.4506.2152; .NET CLR 3.5.30729)
Timestamp: Tue, 6 Dec 2011 20:05:28 UTC


Message: Permission denied
Line: 89
Char: 3
Code: 0
URI: https://s-static.ak.facebook.com/connect/canvas_proxy.php?version=3


Message: Permission denied
Line: 89
Char: 3
Code: 0
URI: https://s-static.ak.facebook.com/connect/canvas_proxy.php?version=3
```